# Unitary matrix eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some hint to solve this problem.

Let U be a unitary matrix. Prove that if λ is an eigenvalue of U, then |λ| = 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a unitary matrix and $(\lambda, x)$ and eigenpair where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$.  Then
$$
||Ux|| = ||\lambda x|| = |\lambda|\,||x|| = ||x|| \iff |\lambda| = 1.
$$

The first equality is the definition of an eigenpair, the second is the homogeneity property of norms, and the third equality is because a unitary matrix preserves norms.  That is, $||U x|| = ||x||$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$